# How to combine two list with the different element?

Tags: list, haskell

How to combine two list with the different element? The problem like this:

[image]

Comment: The problem is *"How to write setDiff function"*?

Comment: I suspect your question is getting down-voted because `setDiff` isn't often described as "combining two lists". Changing the title to what @soon suggested may help.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `(\\)` function:

```
[2,4,6,8,10] \\ [3,4,5,6] == [2,8,10]
```

Haskell comes with a lot of built-in functions. Especially for simple tasks like this, you'll often find one that does the job. But how do you find one?

The first step is to determine the type of your desired function. In this case you're looking for a function that takes two lists with elements of the same type (`a`) and produces a list with elements of that same type:

```
[a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Next [search Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) for functions that match that type. `(\\)` is near the top of the results. It includes the following documentation:

> The `\\` function is list difference (non-associative). In the result of `xs \\ ys`, the first occurrence of each element of `ys` in turn (if any) has been removed from `xs`. Thus
>
> ```
> (xs ++ ys) \\ xs == ys.
> ```
>
> It is a special case of `deleteFirstsBy`, which allows the programmer to supply their own equality test.